# Rijndaelcipher mix column query

Tags: rijndael

I quote a wikipedi para that says

The operation consists in the modular multiplication of two four-term polynomials whose coefficients are elements of ${\displaystyle \operatorname {GF} (2^{8})} $. The modulo used for this operation is $ x^{4}+1$.

The first four-term polynomial coefficients are defined by the state column ${\displaystyle {\begin{bmatrix}b_{3}&b_{2}&b_{1}&b_{0}\end{bmatrix}}} $, which contains four bytes. Each byte is a coefficient of the four-term so that

${\displaystyle b(x)=b_{3}x^{3}+b_{2}x^{2}+b_{1}x+b_{0}}$

The doubt i have is are $ b_3, b_2,b_1,b_0$ all polynomial in $GF(2^8)$.  for example if i have an $8$ bit number $11111111$ does $b_3=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$ i.e the polynomial associated with the $5$ most significant bits? i am really confused about this ? can someone explain with any example of how the Mix Columns algo work?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the field $\textrm{GF}(2^8)$ as a "given", a way to multiply and add bytes (the addition is just XOR, the multiply could be given as a table of 256 by 256 entries; you'll see we need only very few entries:

Then the column represented by $b_3x^3 + b_2x^2 + b_1x+b_0$ is multiplied by $(3x^3 + x^2 + x +2)$ in the usual way, but modulo $x^4+1$ as said, so we consider $x^4$ and $1$ to be the same, as $x^5$ and $x$ etc. and in general $x^n$ is just reduced to $x^{n \pmod{4}}$.

So first the usual multiplication gives

$$ 3b_3 x^6 + (3b_2 + b_3)x^5 + (b_3+b_2+3b_1)x^4 + (2b_3+b_2+b_1+3b_0)x^3 + (2b_2 + b_1 + b_0)x^2 + (2b_1+b_0)x + 2b_0$$

where (!) $3b_3$ is just the multiplication in $\textrm{GF}(2^8)$, so we only need the rows in the multiplication table corresponding to $2$ and $3$ are these are the only non-trivial coefficients that are used in the field multiplications.

Then we can use that $x^6 \equiv x^2, x^5 \equiv x, x^4 \equiv 1$ to get a third degree polynomial (gathering coefficients again):

$$(2b_3 + b_2+b_1+2b_0)x^3 + (3b_3 + 2b_2 + b_1 + b_0)x^2 + (b_3+3b_2+2b_1+b_0)x+ (b_3+b_2+3b_1+2b_0)$$

(maybe some small mistakes here..., check the computations by hand, I'm doing them from screen; less optimal)
The additions are still xor's of course. This shows formulae to find the new values of the column from the old one, and if done properly we get a nice circular matrix multiplication. We only need multiplication with a small number of coefficients anyway, also for the inverse, and this multiplication of bytes is indeed in itself a modular bit-polynomial multiplication. The above had multiplications on byte level, so one level of abstraction up.

I think the [Wikipedia explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_MixColumns) is quite adequate and covers these points too.

In practice, we either compute it in hardware or using tables in software, never by actually computing with polynomials over finite fields.